# Robotframework: ValueError: Element locator 'locator(332,400)' did not match any elements

Tags: appium, robotframework

I am trying to setup a automaited test. I am useing RobotFramework and the AppiumLibrary
I am using click a point when tap a button, because I use Flutter on my apps.
When i try to input the text on:

> http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html

said I must use locator, text
but when I try to use locator with my coordinate

```
click a point          332      400
sleep                  2s
input text             locator(332,400)     testing
```

and then this notification appears

```
ValueError: Element locator 'locator(332,400)' did not match any elements.
```

I already googling and cannot find the answer, please help me, thankyou

Comment: can you try use xpath instead of this ?

Comment: i try the xpath and this happen

ValueError: Element locator '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.ImageView/android.widg
et.EditText[1]' did not match any elements.

Comment: Which tool u use to inspect ? I think u adding wrong xpath

Comment: I use Appium sir, and I found on Selected Element, there is xpath for the text box

Comment: it's a bit hard to help you because we can't inspect your app. but by the way, you should try to wait for your XPath like "Wait until element is visible" set it to 10s timeout.

Comment: I use "Click Element At Coordinates" and it seems to work just fine. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a valid locator from its locator introduction
http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Introduction
[image]

i.e: input text    id=my_element    TextToInput

Comment: there is no id appears on appium, because i'm using flutter.. so I need to tap my button using coordinate X,Y. I don't know how to choose the text box and input the value because there is no id